# lxml package freezing during install

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the pyquery module, which requires lxml. Whenever I try to install the lxml module, though, it gets exactly this far:

```
$ sudo python3.7 -m pip install lxml
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting lxml
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/4a/b085a04d6dad79aa5c00c65c9b2bbcb2c6c22e5ac341e7968e0ad2c57e2f/lxml-4.3.0.tar.gz (2.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.5MB 1.2MB/s 
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... /
```

...and then the `/` stops spinning. If I leave it running for more than about a minute, the Pi freezes.

Since I'm using a different version of Python 3 than comes installed on the pi, `sudo apt-get install python3-lxml` doesn't work either (unless there's a way to get this working that I don't know about). Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: For Arm there is no binary package for your version Python, so pip will (should) try to compile the package. You may have to wait a bit longer than a couple of minutes before giving up. Alternatively you could try python3-lxml from the Raspbian Buster repo. Search the web on how to install single packages from a different repo.

Comment: I've been getting the same problem - @Dirk - it's not just a matter of waiting, it seems to be killing my pi altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the swap file gets filled to 100% and then the Pi is frozen. If using a HDD you can increase the swap size to e.g. 1024. This works for me. Compilation occupies up to 170MB of swap on a Pi3.